# Radial Time Picker Dialog to Dialog Preference

Tags: android, dialog, preference

I want to implement radial time picker in preference activity, so I have to convert radial time picker from dialog fragment to dialog preference. Btw, I use radial time picker from better picker library. 
I have tried to convert it but no success so far

Here is radial time picker from the library

[RadialTimePickerDialog.java](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers/blob/master/library/src/com/doomonafireball/betterpickers/radialtimepicker/RadialTimePickerDialog.java)

could someone help? or anyone has another idea for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom `Preference` subclass, let's call it `TimePickerPreference`. Then add this method in it that you will have to call when inflating the preferences:

```
public void setupListener(final FragmentManager fragmentManager){
        setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Calendar calendar = getCurrentValueCalendar();
                RadialTimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = RadialTimePickerDialog
                        .newInstance(new RadialTimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout radialPickerLayout, int hour, int minute) {
                                int newValue = hour * 60 + minute;
                                if (callChangeListener(newValue))
                                    setMinutesSinceMidnight(newValue);
                            }
                        }, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
                timePickerDialog.show(fragmentManager, "FRAG_TAG_TIME_PICKER");
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

In my case this was modeling a minutesSinceMidnight but you get the point.

Notice the `callChangeListener(newValue)` - this will allow you to use this nicely from the outside using a `OnPreferenceChangeListener` and will support the whole model of allowing the change listener to veto the change.

Obviously this is still assuming that the activity is a `FragmentActivity` (which the `PreferenceActivity` isn't). I've used a `FragmentActivity` with a `PreferenceFragment` instead. If you need to support older versions, there's a github compat version of it: [android-support-v4-preferencefragment](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment).